# When to execute asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity

I have this activity. Inside activity I have 3 asynctask, I need one of them to be executed in the onCreate method. I want to implement an refresh button following tutorial on this website http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/ (almost at the end) but the problem is I want the action bar refresh button to execute asynctask, that is first called in the onCreate method. Example activity :

```
package info.androidhive.actionbar;

import info.androidhive.actionbar.model.SpinnerNavItem;
import info.androidhive.info.actionbar.adapter.TitleNavigationAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.SearchView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {

// action bar
private ActionBar actionBar;

// Refresh menu item
private MenuItem refreshMenuItem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new SyncData.execute(); //this is example of my implementation I call my asynctask here 
    actionBar = getActionBar();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
....
}

/**
 * On selecting action bar icons
 * */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Take appropriate action for each action item click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    ...
    case R.id.action_refresh:
        // refresh
        refreshMenuItem = item;
        // load the data from server
        new SyncData().execute();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/**
 * Async task to load the data from server
 * **/
private class SyncData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // set the progress bar view
        refreshMenuItem.setActionView(R.layout.action_progressbar);

        refreshMenuItem.expandActionView();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // not making real request in this demo
        // for now we use a timer to wait for sometime
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        refreshMenuItem.collapseActionView();
        // remove the progress bar view
        refreshMenuItem.setActionView(null);
    }
};

}
```

So by following this tutorial on the line

```
refreshMenuItem.setActionView(R.layout.action_progressbar);
```

I am stucked with null reference to refreshMenuItem. Is there workaround ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. When you run your `AsyncTask` in `onCreate(..)`, your `MenuItem` is not yet initialized - as it gets initialized when user presses the corresponding button, for some odd reason, and this happens inside `onOptionsItemSelected()`. That's why you get your `NullPointerException`.

To avoid this, initialize the `MenuItem` in `onPrepareOptionsMenu(..)` or in the `onCreateOptionsMenu(..)`.

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    refreshMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);
    return true;
}
```

**Upd** But the more important is where you should execute your `AsyncTask`. You should definitely execute only when all of your `Activity`'s class members used by it are in a "safe state"; by this, I mean that if your `Activity` has `SomeObject someObj` member, and you call `someObj.setSometh()` from within your `AsyncTask`, you rely on the assumption, that your `someObj != null`.

So, it is up to you to choose when to run your `AsyncTask` in the first place.

Comment: yea, I gave that asynctask some conditions and it works now :)

Comment: Glad for you, be careful, `Activity`'s lifecycle is a tough thing, there are a lot of things to consider :)